# asp.net core mvc .net8 return custom view on 403

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, model-view-controller, authorization

How I can show custom forbidden view?

My asp.net core mvc project have cookie based authorization

```cs
      services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Authorization/Login";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
            });
```

There are my policies

```cs
        services.AddAuthorizationBuilder()
            .SetDefaultPolicy(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build())
            .AddPolicy(ApplicationPolicies.SuperAdministrator, op => op
                .RequireRole(ApplicationClaimValues.SuperAdministrator))
            .AddPolicy(ApplicationPolicies.Administrator, op => op
                .RequireRole(ApplicationClaimValues.SuperAdministrator, ApplicationClaimValues.Administrator))
            .AddPolicy(ApplicationPolicies.Reviewer, op => op
                .RequireRole(ApplicationClaimValues.Reviewer, ApplicationClaimValues.Administrator,
                    ApplicationClaimValues.SuperAdministrator));
```

How can I show view on Shared/ExtraPages/Forbidden.cshtml when AuthorizeAttribute on my action:

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateContentCommand command)
    {
        await mediator.Send(command);
        return Redirect($"{Url.Action("Index")}?pageName={command.PageName}");
    }
```

gives 403 status code?

Now I'm getting an empty response from the server with a 403 status.

Comment: FYI: I can't write custom authorize attribute. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any update? Did my reply help you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your codes, your AccessDeniedPath is `/Account/AccessDenied`. So if you want to return the custom 403 fordden page, you should write the Account controller and the AccessDenied view.

Then inside this AccessDenied view, you could set content according to your requirement.

More details, you could refer to below example:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class AccountController : Controller
{

    public IActionResult AccessDenied()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

View：

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AccessDenied";
}

<h1>AccessDenied</h1>

AccessDenied
```

My Authorize attribute:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "test")]
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
    return View();
}
```

My program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
      .AddCookie(options =>
      {
          options.LoginPath = "/Authorization/Login";
          options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
      });


builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder()
    .SetDefaultPolicy(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build())
    .AddPolicy("test", op => op
        .RequireRole("admin"));
```

Result:

[image]